# Matching Flags At Beginning of String (Optional, Unspecific Order)

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

**My problem:**

I need to match a few flags at the beginning of a string which are optional and can be in an unspecific order.

**What I've got:**

Lets say my flags are '+', '-' and '0'. If I use

```
[\-\+0]*
```

the flags can be in an unspecific order but they are matched multiple times. If I use

```
\-?\+?0?
```

the flags are matched just once but with the given order. I guess I need to use a lookaround assertion somehow, but I don't know how.

**Update**

This is what I'm trying to match (a few examples):

- -+0
- +0-
- +
- -
- or nothing at all

but the flags should not be repeated:

- --+
- +00-

Comment: is that the begining of a string or begining of a line?

Comment: It's at the beginning of a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Optional Flags in Any Order, Without Reusing a Flag

We'll start with a pure-regex solution. At the bottom, we'll discuss other options.

Use this at the beginning of your pattern:

```
^([-+0]?)(?!.?\1)(?:([-+0])(?!\2))?[-+0]?(?![-+0])
```

See what matches and fails in **[the regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/tU4fQ4/3)**.

This is more readable with a free-spacing regex:

```
(?x)             # free-spacing mode
^                # beginning of string
([-+0]?)         # capture optional flag to Group 1
(?!.?\1)         # check that chars 2 and 3 don't repeat Group 1

(?:              # optional non-capture group
   ([-+0])          # Group 2: match flag
   (?!\2)           # check that the next char is not the same
)?               # end group

[-+0]?           # match optional flag

(?![-+0])        # check that the next char is not a flag
```

**Explanation**

- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- `([-+0]?)(?!.?\1)` captures an optional flag to Group 1, and the negative lookahead asserts that neither of the following chars is the one matched by Group 1
- `(?:([-+0])(?!\2))?` This optional capture group contains Group 2, which captures a second flag, and the negative lookahead asserting that the following char is not the one matched by Group 2
- `[-+0]?` optionally matches a third flag
- `(?![-+0])` asserts that the next char is not a flag

**Other Options**

Doing it in a single-step is unwieldy, especially if your requirements change. Another option would be to build all the flags using `^[-+0]+`, then to iterate through the characters in the string, adding them to a set (unique elements). If an element is already in the set, you fail the validation.

Comment: FYI: added demo and explanation. :)

Comment: Thank you, seems exactly what I was looking for. Unfortunately I have 5 flags and I hoped it would be a simpler / smaller regex. Without your explanation I would have never understood your solution.

Comment: Thanks for the green checkmark. Yes, a pure regex solution is interesting but a bit unwieldy. Added a section to discuss other options. :)